# Webpage opened inside an iphone app doesn't stop sound after closing

Tags: iphone, html, html5-audio

I have a mobile minisite that is reached from some iphone/android apps through banners

the site integrates a html `<audio>` tag that plays some sound after clicking a button

While in some apps everything works great, in a certain app - while the banner is clicked the minisite is opened in a some kind of browser inside the app (screenshot provided below)

the problem is that when the user closes that browser (by click the X button) while the sound is playing - the sound doesn't stop

is there anyway to know when the browser is closed in order to stop the sound manually?

I guess `window.onbeforeunload` won't work here because if the site was unloaded - the sound would stop anyway

screenshot of the kind of browser I'm talking about:

[image: iphone in app browser]

thank you very much

Comment: I if the window isn't being `unload`ed then it's the fault of the "app". There isn't much you can do without the other developer doing something on their end. BTW, that is by far the best example image I've ever seen on SO.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to setup an event listener for the `blur` event and just pause the audio then.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that up, even though I suspect that this event might also be triggered in other circumstances.